# Not sure how to setup amd drivers with xorg on openBSD?

Tags: driver, xorg, openbsd, amd-gpu

I deleted my Linux install and recently tried OpenBSD but I am not sure how to set up a GUI environment and xserver. I have a R9 290 GPU and I saw that it should be supported by the Radeon driver however I don't know how to download or configure it.

Comment: This probably doesn't belong here, since it is not a programming question, rather about system installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All drivers are included in the default install and should Just Work©. That said, your Radeon GPU may need firmware whose license prevents OpenBSD from including it. Running `fw_update` should install it if it's needed.

Other than that, you just need to configure X. Everything's included in the base system, including the window managers cwm and fvwm. If you want another, you can install it from ports. To configure X, read the very well-written [FAQ entry](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq11.html).

Enjoy!